# c++ define function later (in other library)?

Tags: c++

I am writing an Abstract Library / Class to access a Database.
I want to make it Abstract so that i can easily change the database im using without to much trouble later in my program. My goal is, to reduce my code changes if im changing the database to only the place where im connecting to the database (1x changing the included header file / connect method)

Currently im having trouble creating the code for different Conditions.
I have a Base class named ICondition, which currently doesn't have any methods in it
And my inhertianced class “WhereCondition” which should represent the WHERE condition in for example a SQL statement.
Not every SQL database has the same syntax some want (for bools) (just an example)
WHERE field = ‘0’ 
some only accept the bool only without the quote. 
So I want the proper Implementation for that database type to generate the SQL command,
The problem is I cant make WhereCondition virtual because then I cant generate a WhereCondition without changing the include files. What is an working solution for that problem?

Layout

LIB:

- DatabaseAbstraction

  - IDatabase.hpp – pure virtual class
  - ICondition.hpp – pure virtual class
  - WhereCondition.hpp
  - WhereCondition.cpp
- SQLiteAbstraction (for the SQLite implementation of the Database)

  - SQLiteDatabase.hpp – sqlite implementation of IDatabase
  - SQLiteDatabase.cpp
- MYSQLAbstraction (for the MYSQL implementation of the Database)

  - MYSQLDatabase.hpp – mysql implementation of IDatabase
- MYSQLDatabase.cpp

Idatabase.hpp

```
Class Idatabase {
    public:
        Value select(const std::string& fieldName, const Icondition& condition);
}
```

WhereCondition.hpp

```
Class WhereCondition : public Icondition {
    private:
        std::string fieldName
        Value data;
        ….

    public:
        WhereCondition(const std::string& fieldName, const Value& data); 
}
```

Programm
main.cpp

```
#include <SQLiteAbstraction/SqliteDatabase.hpp> // Only file I want to change
sqliteDatabase.connect(...)
```

otherfile

```
    #include <DatabaseAbstraction/Idatabase.hpp>
    #include <DatabaseAbstraction/WhereCondition.hpp>
void fun(IDatabase db) {
    db.select(“field”, WhereCondition(“otherfield”, true)) //Wouldn’t work if WhereCondition is Virtual
}
```

Now the SQLite implementation of select gets called, but I need a way to convert the WhereCondition to a string that suits the conventions that SQLite has for its SQL commands.
Is there a way to add a function to the WhereCondition class that can be implemented / changed by the proper Database Implementation?

Comment: Honestly, there's a reason SQL caught on and relational databases are very used to it. Adding a layer like this has never really worked, in my experience. If you're worried about portability, just stick to Standard SQL as much as you can, and don't write a billion different queries...